# Docker listening in container but not answering outside, why?

Tags: docker

I have a docker container built with "EXPOSE 8000" among its instructions.  I started the process like this:

```
sudo docker run -t -i -P imagename
```

The process in the container is listening on 8000.

```
# netstat -a
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 localhost:8000          *:*                     LISTEN     
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
#
```

On the host (i.e., outside the container), I see that port 49164 is bound to container port 8000:

```
[S-22]jeff@siegfried:~ $ sudo docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
0b0e333c6ec9        lkz:latest                 "/bin/bash"         About an hour ago   Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:49164->8000/tcp   lkxyz__2015-01-18_202737   
[S-22]jeff@siegfried:~ $
```

Inded, `docker inspect` says (among other things)

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "docker0",
    "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.16",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "PortMapping": null,
    "Ports": {
        "8000/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "49164"
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

And yet, I can't talk to the container.  Outside,

```
[S-22]jeff@siegfried:~ $ telnet localhost 49164
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
1,[S-22] jeff@siegfried:~ $
```

while inside,

```
# telnet localhost 8000
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /

[18/Jan/2015 23:00:59] "GET /" 200 4066
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
```

I would expect the telnet to 49164 on the outside to return html as it does on the inside.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Aha, this might be that the container is listening really only to localhost. Doing the same thing on host siegfried, I can connect with `telnet localhost 8000` but not with `telnet siegfried 8000`. OK, so now how do I fix this...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You probably want to have the service you're running in the container to listen on `0.0.0.0` rather than `127.0.0.1`

Comment: this was a lifesaver. Using docker for Apache Spark, spark://0.0.0.0:7077

Comment: how do we do this in windows 10 with docker? listen to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: In our case the port was listening on 0.0.0.0, but we needed to reset Docker  to factory defaults (Docker Preferences/Bomb tab) and reinstall images.

Comment: Just to confirm, yes this is the behaviour you'll see when Docker is accepting incoming connections but the service you're running inside Docker is rejecting them.  I also had to change the Dockerised service to listen on 0.0.0.0 to fix the problem, but the Docker config itself was otherwise unchanged.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54102318/542251) goes into details as to why this works

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect 172.17.0.16:8000 from the host.
I had a similar problem with nginx.
I replaced 127.0.0.1:8000 to 172.17.0.16:8000 inside the container and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

bind port 8000 of the container to TCP port 8000

> docker run -d -p 8000:8000 image-name