# Run Gatsby with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gatsby

I am trying to run Gatsby with Docker Compose.
From what I understand the Gatsby site is running in my docker container.
I map port 8000 of the container to port 8000 on my localhost. 
But when looking on `localhost:8000` I am not getting my gatsby site.

I use the following `Dockerfile` to build the image with `docker build -t nxtra/gatsby .`:

```
FROM node:8.12.0-alpine

WORKDIR /project

COPY ./package.json /project/package.json
COPY ./.entrypoint/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

RUN apk update \
  && apk add bash \
  && chmod +x /entrypoint.sh \
  && npm set progress=false \
  && npm install -g yarn gatsby-cli

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

`entrypoints.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

yarn install
gatsby develop
```

docker-compose.yml ran with `docker-compose up`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  gatsby:
    image: nxtra/gatsby
    ports:
    - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
    - ./:/project
    tty: true
```

`docker ps` shows that port 8000 is forwarded `0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp`.
Inspecting my container with `docker inspect --format='{{.Config.ExposedPorts}}' id` confirms the exposure of the port ->  `map[8000/tcp:{}]`

`docker tops` on the container shows the following processes are running in the container:

```
18465               root                0:00                {entrypoint.sh} /bin/bash /entrypoint.sh
18586               root                0:11                node /usr/local/bin/gatsby develop
18605               root                0:00                /usr/local/bin/node /project/node_modules/jest-worker/build/child.js
18637               root                0:00                /bin/bash
```

Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml are situated in the root of my Gatsby project.
My project is running correctly when I run it without docker `gatsby develop`.

What am I doing wrong to get the Gatsby site that runs in my container to be visible on localhost:8000?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My issue was that Gatsby was only listening to requests within the container, [like this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015344/docker-listening-in-container-not-answering-outside#28016078). Make sure you've configured Gatsby for the host `0.0.0.0`.  Take this (somewhat hacky) setup as an example:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN npm install --global gatsby-cli
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  gatsby:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    entrypoint: gatsby
    volumes:
      - .:/app

  develop:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

You can run Gatsby commands from a container:
`docker-compose run gatsby info`

Or run the development server:
`docker-compose up develop`

Comment: `gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0` did the trick, thanks!