# How do you dockerize a WebSocket Server?

Tags: docker, go, websocket, dockerfile

I'm having trouble with putting my WebSocket server in a Docker container.

This is the server code, which writes to a new connection with "connected".

```
// server.go
func RootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    upgrader := websocket.Upgrader{ // (Uses gorilla/websocket)
        ReadBufferSize:  4096,
        WriteBufferSize: 4096,
    }

    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err = conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("connected")); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("server is running")

    // For graceful shutdown
    stop := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(stop, os.Interrupt)

    server := http.Server{Addr: "localhost:8000"}
    defer server.Close()

    http.HandleFunc("/", RootHandler)

    go func() {
        err := server.ListenAndServe()
        if err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    <-stop
}
```

Here is the client:

```
// client.go
func main() {
    connection, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial("ws://localhost:8000", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, b, err := connection.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b)) // "connected"
}
```

Running `server.go` then `client.go` prints "connected", showing that the code is working. Now I want to put the server in a Docker container. This is `dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.11.4-alpine3.8
COPY . $GOPATH/src/websocket-test
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/websocket-test
RUN ["go", "build", "server.go"]
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["./server"]
```

I use these commands to build and start the container, exposing 8000/tcp.

```
docker build -t websocket-test .
docker run -p 8000:8000 websocket-test
```

I can confirm that the server is running because it prints "server is running". If I start `client.go` outside the container, it panics:

```
panic: read tcp [::1]:60328->[::1]:8000: read: connection reset by peer
```

What I expect is the same outcome as before—printing "connected" on the client side. The error message means that the server dropped the connection before the handshake. I don't understand the "60328" number. As far as I know, WebSocket doesn't change ports on upgrade, so I should be okay with exposing just 8000.

I do not know what I must change to be able to connect via WebSocket to my server.

Comment: Your server needs to listen on it's external interface, not localhost. Try changing `localhost:8000` in the server code to `0.0.0.0:8000`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: listening in container, not answering outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015344/docker-listening-in-container-not-answering-outside)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When you specify a hostname or IP address​ to listen on (in this case `localhost` which resolves to `127.0.0.1`), then your server will only listen on that IP address.

Listening on `localhost` isn't a problem when you are outside of a Docker container. If your server only listens on `127.0.0.1:8000`, then your client can easily connect to it since the connection is also made from `127.0.0.1`.

When you run your server inside a Docker container, it'll only listen on `127.0.0.1:8000` as before. The `127.0.0.1` is a local loopback address and it not accessible outside the container.

When you fire up the docker container with `-p 8000:8000`, it'll forward traffic heading to `127.0.0.1:8000` to the container's IP address, which in my case is `172.17.0.2`.

The container gets an IP addresses within the docker0 network interface (which you can see with the `ip addr ls` command)

So, when your traffic gets forwarded to the container on `172.17.0.2:8000`, there's nothing listening there and the connection attempt fails.

#### The fix:

The problem is with the listen address:

```
server := http.Server{Addr: "localhost:8000"}
```

To fix your problem, change it to

```
server := http.Server{Addr: ":8000"}
```

That'll make your server listen on all it container's IP addresses.

#### Additional info:

When you expose ports in a Docker container, Docker will create iptables rules to do the actual forwarding. See this. You can view these rules with:

```
iptables -n -L 
iptables -t nat -n -L
```

Comment: just wanted to share my experience about this, even in a completely different language / framework (dart). This answer (and question) is "spot on" understanding serving ports and addresses inside docker. Thank you

Comment: thanks you, great explanation, just wanted to add that depending on the language/framework being used an IP address might be required. In that case IP `0.0.0.0` means all IPs