# Get PHP container on port 8000 after php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, docker, port

I can't container to listen on port 8000, even after adding the port mapping on my docker-compose.yml file.

All relevant files can be found here: https://github.com/salvatore-esposito/laravel-dockerized

I ran the following commands: `docker-compose exec app php artisan serve` and it has run successfully.

Anyway if I go inside the container, curl works as expected, but it doesn't work from the outside. The connection gets refused.

I fetched the ip using `docker-machine ip`

Please note that I mapped the outside-inside port in my container via docker-compose.yml even if in the repository there si no map.

I tried to copy all files to a built image and launch:

`docker run --rm -p 8000:8000 --name laravel salvio/php-laravel php artisan serve`

and

`docker exec -it laravel bash`

Once more time if a run "curl localhost:80" and "curl localhost:8000" the former doesn't work and the latter it does whereas if I take the container's ip via docker inspect name_container and digit curl ip_of_container:8000 nothing.

Comment: php artisan should not be used for hosting laravel sites, you should configure apache to point to the laravel folder. You could bind `8000:80` to be able to access the container from to the host using `80000`

Comment: I know, but for example if I'd use only a php container without apache, should it work? My curiosity is about the fact that I can't get access to the container via port 8000, even if there is the internal php server that's listen.

Comment: Where does it list that it runs the `serve` command? https://github.com/salvatore-esposito/laravel-dockerized/blob/master/init.sh. @Salvio

Comment: I did it manually by bash: docker-compose exec app php artisan serve.

I told it: this is only my curioisty cause everything works perfectly by using port 80.

Comment: After all I get the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369664/how-to-use-php-artisan-serve-inside-docker-container

Comment: Did you try the following command: `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0` in the container? @Salvio

Comment: Yeah and it's working. I didn't know that laravel local server accept incoming request only from localhost.

Comment: This is not specific for the internal php server, this is the default for most applications. I updated my answer to include the host info, could you mark it as solved? @Salvio

Comment: Could you mark the answer as solution by clicking the "Checkmark" under the up/down vote? This way it is easier for people to find the solution if they face the same problem @Salvio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `docker-compose exec` a command keeps running until it's interactive session is stopped(by using `ctrl-c` or closing the terminal) because it isn't running as a service. To be able to keep the following command running

```
docker-compose exec app php artisan serve
```

you would have to open 2 terminals, 1 with the command and 1 to connect to the container and ping port `8000`

If you want to access your container port 8000 you would have to expose the port `8000` in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/salvatore-esposito/laravel-dockerized/blob/master/.config/php/Dockerfile):

```
# rest of docker file
# Copy existing application directory permissions
#COPY --chown=www-data:www-data ./code /var/www/html

# Change current user to www-data
#USER www-data

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 80000
```

and map it to your host in `docker-compose`([file](https://github.com/salvatore-esposito/laravel-dockerized/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)):

```
app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .config/php/Dockerfile
    image: salvio/php-composer-dev
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./code/:/var/www/html
      - .config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - myproject-network
```

Please keep in mind `php artisan serve` binds to `localhost:8000`. This means this is only reachable within the container. Use

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

to bind to the shared network interface. Checkout the following resources:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54022753/6310593
2. [How do you dockerize a WebSocket Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101508/how-do-you-dockerize-a-websocket-server/54102318#54102318)

Comment: I used two terminal and before trying by browser. I tried with curl and was unreacheble.

Comment: What commands did you run? 1. `./init` 2. `docker-compose exec app php artisan serve` in terminal one and 3. `docker-compose exec app ping localhost:8000` in the second terminal? @Salvio

Comment: When laravel is ready and the container responses on port 80 I run docker-compose exec app php artisan serve. No in the second terminal I run "curl ip_of_app_container:8000". Anyway to launch all I run ./init.sh

Comment: If you wish to access an container port you will have to expose the ports(8000) in your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose`. Checkout the updated answer for an example @Salvio

Comment: I do it by copy all file in the image and run the single image. I exposed 8000 but nothing.

Comment: Doing `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0` has worked for me.   
Thank you!